# Convert GeoTIFF to DWG

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, color, cad, dwg

I like to convert a georeferenced tif-file into a dwg-drawing.
At first I convert the raster into a polygon. The result is Grey-coloured picture
When I "Export to CAD" the polygon it is still Grey.
How can I secure the original color scale?

I am using IBSCAD and ArcGIS.

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't "Export to CAD" a Raster file. You should just be able to add the image in your CAD Software. Could you add information detailing the CAD Software you using? Are you sure the Coordinate system of the TIFF is the same as the data you are trying to view in CAD?

Comment: No, you're right, I can't. I tried to convert the raster into a polygon. That's what I forgot. The used CAD Software is IBSCAD. The coodinate systems are equal.

Comment: Can you load the image into IBSCAD? I am not familiar with the software, but I guess loading the image in is the first step and then working through the loading process options may reveal a result. I cannot speak German, but it might be worthwhile contacting the software manufacturers directly: https://www.ibscad.de/support/support-anfrage/ ?

Comment: I pulled a ticket of the Support guys. Let's see if there is a possibility. But as far as I'm concerned, IBSCAD has Problems with tif files because of the size. I'd prefer a way to realize the conversion with ArcGIS.